# VBA to format border of Chart bar from corresponding cell

Tags: excel, vba

I use following VBA to format Chart bar color from corresponding cell. It works fine.
But now I need to add 1 more line, to format Chart bar's border as cell's border.
I can't figure out how to do this. Can anybody help me please?

```
Sub ColorOfChart1()
    
   
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, cht As Chart, c As Range, b As Border
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    k = 0
    For i = 1 To 54
        Set cht = ws.ChartObjects("Cluster" & i).Chart
        For j = 1 To cht.SeriesCollection.Count
            Set c = ws.Cells(68, j + 5 + k)
            Set b = c.Borders(xlEdgeBottom) 'Just using bottom border, in case
                                            ' not all borders are consistent..
            With cht.SeriesCollection(j)
                .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = c.Interior.Color
                .Format.Line.Weight = 0.5
                .Border.LineStyle = b.LineStyle '<< copy each border property over
                .Border.Color = b.Color
            End With
        Next j
        k = k + 10
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: If you record a macro while setting the cell border color you'll see the properties you need to read from.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should be close:

```vb
Sub ColorOfChart()
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, cht As Chart, c As Range, b As Border
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    k = 0
    For i = 1 To 54
        Set cht = ws.ChartObjects("Cluster" & i).Chart
        For j = 1 To cht.SeriesCollection.Count
            Set c = ws.Cells(68, j + 5 + k)
            Set b = c.Borders(xlEdgeBottom) 'Just using bottom border, in case
                                            ' not all borders are consistent..
            With cht.SeriesCollection(j)
                .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = c.Interior.Color
                .Format.line.Weight = 0.5
                .Border.LineStyle = b.LineStyle '<< copy each border property over
                .Border.Color = b.Color
            End With
        Next j
        k = k + 10
    Next i
End Sub
```

Note you don't need the RGB breakdown for the `ForeColor` - that will take a Long

Comment: Thank you for fast reply. But I don't want border color, I want border style to be same..

Comment: Then you'll need to copy the border color/width/linestyle etc  - each property one-by-one for the ones you want to replicate.  See example above

Comment: Your code giving errors.

Comment: "Your code giving errors" - that is not very useful - what errors, and on which line(s) ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Because I get several of them.                                                         
 Variable not defined:  Set chrtObj = ws.ChartObjects("Cluster" & i).Chart

Comment: Fixed that line - see above

Comment: Now I get error in this line. Type mismatch: .Format.Fill.ForeColor = c.Interior.Color

Comment: See edits above - if your cell borders are not consistent then it's best to pick one border (in this case the bottom one) to read the properties.

Comment: Tim, thank you for time you spend to solve my problem. Now when I run macro. It makes all cells borders same. Let's say if I make border of F68 bold. It makes all cells in row 68 bold..

Comment: There's nothing in the code I posted which would set the cell borders, so I'm not sure what's going on with your worksheet.  Can you update your post and add your current code?

Comment: updated. But i noticed. It is not formating all cell borders style. When I run macro. It does when I change 1 cell , it formats all at the same time. without running any VBA

Comment: I have no idea why it’s doing that